# Is there an HTTP Connection Timeout in client-side JS/Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, timeout

I'm using Angular's [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) to make HTTP requests and I'd like to specify a timeout for them.

I know I can use HTTPInterceptors and add a timeout to RxJS operators, however, these apply to the whole request which I don't want to abort if data transfer is in progress, only if the browser is hanging while trying to connect.

The kind of timeout I need is available in Node.js for example which is well explained [here](https://shuheikagawa.com/blog/2017/05/13/http-request-timeouts-in-javascript/):

> Let's say you called `socket.setTimeout(300)` to set the timeout as 300
>   ms, and it took 100 ms for DNS lookup, 100 ms for making a connection
>   with a remote server, 200 ms for the remote server to send response
>   headers, 50 ms for transferring the first half of the response body
>   and another 50 ms for the rest. While the entire request & response
>   took more than 500 ms, timeout event is not emitted at all.

Is it possible to have a timeout like this in an Angular app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the source code for the HttpClient. The code that actually deals with the underlying XMLHttpRequest is the class HttpXhrBackend, in source file named [xhr.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L78)

Unfortunately, HttpXhrBackend just uses the default settings of XMLHttpRequest, and does not provide a way to set the XMLHttpRequest's timeout value.

I have seen suggestions for using RxJS operators to shorten the effective timeout,
but that's a bit of a hack, and doesn't really do what you are asking for.

So, technically, the answer to your question is "No", not with the stock Angular HttpClient, but I suppose that you could create your own implementation of HttpBackend and attempt to inject that.

P.S. [This article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/insiders-guide-into-interceptors-and-httpclient-mechanics-in-angular-103fbdb397bf) shows how to provide a custom HttpBackend implementation.

Comment: Why would using RxJS operators be considered a hack

Comment: Using RxJS operators in and of itself is not a hack, but trying to shorten the XMLHttpRequest's timeout by simply terminating the connection early is, IMHO, a hack. YMMV

Comment: Fair, would you also classify aborting a request with something like `AbortController` a hack?

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek Thank you for the investigation. I accept this as an answer because I see no reasonable solution to this for now either. Somehow extending HttpClient or using some other custom implementation would have more downsides I think, so I just made a [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34421).

Answer (score 0):

For those still seeking a 'hacky' solution you can create an observable and insert an empty/failure after your desired timeout period:

```
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.warn('HTTPErrorResponse caught', error);
    return observableOf({});
  }

  async __sendCommandHTTP(cmd: SoftAPCommand) {
    const URL = this.options.host + cmd.name;

    let result: SoftAPResponse = {
      name: cmd.name,
      payload: {},
      error: false,
    };
    this.logger.debug('[softap-setup starting request');

    await new Promise(resolve => {
      const httpEvent: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
      let returned = false;

      const sub = this.http
        .get<any>(URL, {})
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
        .subscribe(data => httpEvent.next(data));

      // Our cheeky method to ensure a timeout
      setTimeout(async () => {
        if (!returned) {
          this.logger.info('[softap-setup] timeout on ' + result.name);
          httpEvent.next({});
        }
      }, 5000);

      httpEvent.subscribe(data => {
        this.logger.info('[softap-setup] response ', data);
        returned = true;

        switch (cmd.name) {
          case 'scan-ap':
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, 'scans') && data.scans.length) {
              result.payload = data.scans;
            } else {
              result.error = true;
            }
            break;
          default:
            result.payload = data;
            break;
        }

        httpEvent.complete();
        resolve();
      });
    });

    return result;
   
  }
```

Basically either the response or the timeout flags there has been a result. The handleError function also neatly handles any eventual errors that may come along, ie the host isn't available. You could apply other logic in there or even pass along the HTTPErrorResponse object.